# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config.wsgi'

Tags: django

I'm trying to run a .py file and in the file I have this import

```
from config.wsgi import *
import os
from django.template.loader import get_template
from weasyprint import HTML, CSS
from config import settings
```

The whole project works, if I set runserver, the project starts without any problem, but this file does not work. The structure of the project is as follows

```
NombreDelProyecto
--app
---config
----__init__.py
----asgi.py
----settings.py
----wsgy.py
----db.py
---core
----general
----login
----user
----archivodetest.py
```

the case as I say the project works, but in the views of the applications that I have been doing to put imports I get in red underlined but as I say it works for example:

```
from core.general.forms import ActividadForm
```

That comes out in red, if I put in front of the core, app.core as follows

```
from app.core.general.forms import ActividadForm
```

it does not show red but the project does not work and I get the following error

```
from app.core.general.forms import ActividadForm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

I understand that it is the routes or something I did wrong from the beginning, please could someone help me.

Thank you very much.

I tried adding the route, changing the app's route in settings, but to no avail.

Comment: I'd need to at least see your settings.py, the file you say is not working (archivodetest.py?), and the views.py where this file is being called.  `from app.core.general.forms import ActividadForm` is wrong because it looks like that's just the name of your app folder, the modules are within it, so I'm guessing `from core.general.forms import ActividadForm` is probably correct.  I don't know why your IDE is showing it as red.

Answer (score 0):

You've named the file `wsgy.py` but it needs to be `wsgi.py`.

Rename your file in `config` and retry.

To your question, I think its because you're missing the `__init__.py` file in the `general` app.

If you haven't already go one, you'll likely need to have add the same again in your `core` app too.

You probably manually created all of these files and structures I suspect, and if that's the case, please take a look at the documentation regarding [creating new apps inside a django project.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/#creating-the-polls-app)

If you go a bit further up the page, it will also tell you [how to create the initial django project structure with a command.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the answer, I managed to solve it after a lot of testing.
There are two ways, open the project again from the app folder (I had it open in the ProjectName folder).
Or as a second option in pyCharm on the left where the project folders are, I went to the app folder (which is the root) and right clicked and in the menu, Mark Directorie as - Sources root. Then my problem is fixed.
I had all the arcvhiso **init.py**, and where I put the wrong name wsgi.py is that I wrote it wrong here but in the project it was right.
Thank you very much for the help.